# Dynamically filtering large query result for presentation in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, statistics, business-intelligence

We have a system that records data to an SQL Server DB captured from field equipment every minute. This data is used for a number of purposes, one of which is for charting in reports via SSRS.

The issue is that with such a high volume of data, when a report is run for period of for example 3 months, the volume of data returned obviously causes excessive report rendering times.

I've been thinking of finding a way of dynamically reducing the amount of data returned, based on the start and end time periods chosen. Something along the lines of a sliding scale where from the duration between the start and end period, I can apply different levels of filtering so that where larger periods are chosen, more filtering occurs while for smaller periods less or no filtering occurs.

There is still a need to be able to produce higher resolution (as in more data points returned) reports for troubleshooting purposes.

For example:

**Scenario 1:**
User is executing a report for a period of 3 months. Result set returned by the query is reduced for performance reasons without adversely affecting what information the user wants to see (the chart is still representative of the changes over time).

**Scenario 2:**
User executes the report for a period of 1 hour, in order to look for potential indicator(s) of problems with field devices while troubleshooting the system. For this short time period, no filtering is applied.

My first thought was to use a modulo operation on the primary key of the data (which is an identity field), whereby the divisor is chosen depending on the difference between the start and end dates.

**For example**, something like if the difference between the start and end dates for the report execution period is 5 weeks, choose a divisor of 5 and apply a mod to the PK, selecting where the result is equal to zero.

I would love to get feedback as to whether this sounds like a valid approach or whether there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say this has more to do with statistical analysis techniques than SSRS

Comment: By using the modulo and chosing which rows to select, are you not selecting the rest of the rows? Will that not lead to skewed data then? Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: @NickyvV the data is volume data in tanks and generally changes very gradually, so leaving out minute by minute data and going to a filtered set of say 1 row for every 5 minutes does not necessarily affect the representation of tank filing/emptying cycles.

Comment: @MikeD. I tagged SSRS since it is the target platform for this as well as where the issue of too much data for acceptable rendering times was identified. I believe it is still relevant, since it is due to the application of this data in SSRS that I need to find a solution. I agree, the method of achieving the desired outcome is more related to statistical analysis - I'll see what additional tags are relevant.

Comment: I would base the modulo on the minutes portion of the time value - that way you will get consistent time samples, rather than semi-random.

Comment: Thanks for the input @MikeHoney. After re-thinking this, I was leaning towards doing that as well. I agree, it will give a more consistent result set than if it was based on the PK.